# libvirt:: change boot order by command

Tags: libvirt, virsh

Is there any libvirt command that can be used to change boot order for a VM? I know edit xml file can complete this, but I need a command to do this becos I have to shell the command in a script.

Thanks,
Leo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such `virsh` call. However libvirt comes with a python binding. You can easily write a tiny python script you could invoke from your script. Something like this would help you getting started:

```py
import libvirt
from xml.etree import ElementTree
try:
    cnx = libvirt.open()
    domain = cnx.lookupByName('yournamename')
    desc = ElementTree.fromstring(domain.XMLDesc())
    os_node = desc.find('os')
    if os_node is not None:
        boot_nodes = os_node.findall('boot')
        for boot_node in boot_nodes:
          os_node.remove(boot_node)
          
        # TODO Change the order of boot_nodes here
          
        for boot_node in boot_nodes:
          os_node.append(boot_node)
          
    # Write back the definition
    cnx.defineXML(ElementTree.tostring(desc).decode())
except libvirt.libvirtError as err:
    print(err.get_error_message())
```